# How to make the module of app which ask password before installation and don't uninstall without that password?

Tags: android, flutter, uninstallation

I am new Developer. and working on an app, which must not be uninstalled without Master Password. Is this possible and what approach should be used ?

I am using flutter for development. Thanks

Comment: "Is this possible" -- generally no, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this would be done by configuring parental control or some other tool on the device, rather than making the app itself refusing to be uninstalled.